# passing variable with leading '0' in python throws a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> def even_or_odd(n):
...     if(n%2==0):
...             print("even")
...     else:
...             print("odd")
...
>>> even_or_odd(10)
even
>>> even_or_odd(09)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
   even_or_odd(09)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> even_or_odd(9)
odd
```

In the above code, when i pass '09' instead of just 9, i get this error. Can anyone point me to the related documentation for this error in Python?

Comment: Because `09` is not a correct `int` format.

Comment: That's it? just that?

Comment: Yeah, you just can't do this like that, cos, as you saw, it causes Syntax Error. Just stick to regular `9`. You can do things like .05, which equals 0.05 in float, but not leading 0 with int.

Comment: Cool. Thanks then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be (in Python<=2) that an integer literal with a leading zero was interpreted as an octal literal, a base-8 number.  So `011` was equal to `9`.  This is a convention in other languages, like C, but not many people use it anymore (it was useful in the old days when doing base-8 arithmetic was a lot more common).

This was generating some confusion among people who weren't expecting this behavior, and were ending up with integers they weren't expecting from valid-looking literals.  So when Python 3 came out, they decided to adopt a new synxtax for octal literals `0o717` that looks more like the literals for other bases binary `0b0101` and hexadecimal `0x5A2C` (these numbers are not related).

To prevent confusion, the old octal syntax was made a `SyntaxError`, to prevent old code from being used in Python 3 and producing incorrect results. You can read some more about this decision in [PEP 3127](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax)

Comment: Cool.. This is what I was expecting. Thanks Patrick!